# $2D$ Fourier Transform of squares

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm trying to take the 2D Fourier Transform of the below attached image, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this.

I know that by definition, $\text{ rect }(x/A, y/A) = \{1   \text{ for } |x| < A/2, |y| < B/2, \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}\}.$

The Fourier transform of a single rect is $\text{ sinc(x) = $\frac{sin \pi x}{\pi x}$}$ the sinc function.  But from here I don't see how to take the Fourier transform of this partial field of rects.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The Fourier transform is linear, so the Fourier transform of the sum of squares is the sum of the Fourier transforms to the individual squares.

Comment: So in the frequency domain replace each square with a sinc function of appropriate height and width?

Comment: Yes, and the spacing will introduce relative phase factors.